# Will iOS app reject if heap allocation memory reaches 5GB

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I am wondering whether Apple will reject my app if heap & Anonymous VM memory reaches 5GB of allocation.

Can anyone please suggest how I can control this allocation and in which cases will the  app be rejected for memory allocations

[image: Memory allocations in Instruments]

Comment: It is impossible to say how to reduce your memory consumption from the information given - you need to look into the help allocations and see what is consuming the memory.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I take your suggestion. Please say this, is there any problem by reaching Heap allocation memory to more that 10GB?

Comment: Only Apple can answer questions regarding app-store approval.

Answer (score 1):

As long as app works fine on all supported devices and iOS versions they won't reject your app. Did you test this on actual devices? If it doesn't crash then you don't have anything to worry about.